# Locking database on SELECT INTO

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query that return a huge number of rows and I am using `SELECT INTO` (instead of `INSERT INTO`) to avoid having problems with transaction log.

The problem is: while this query is running, I can read objects but not showing them in object explorer. When I try to expand the tables item, for example, I receive the message bellow:

[image]

**Is there a way to avoid this problem?**

Comment: Does this make your `SELECT INTO` query stop working? or you just cant see the table in Object explorer while the query is being executed?

Comment: Just cant see the table in Object explorer while the query is being executed. Actually no one is able to see the objects in object explorer, which makes us having to run this query only at night.

Comment: I'm just curious why you're having to `SELECT INTO` from the table. Do you have a stored procedure that uses this table? Is there any way to do set-based processing instead of selecting into variables?

Comment: This query aggregates a lot of information from a bunch of tables. I store all this info in a new table to be easier to access information in the future. The option is to use `INSERT INTO`, commiting partially time by time, to not get the transaction log full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now here is a Test for you which will give answer to your question...

Open a Query window in SSMS. Write any query which will return any number or rows, could be only one row or maybe 10. and do as follows

### Query window 1

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT *  
   INTO NEW_Test_TABLE
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

### Query Window 2

Now Open another window and write a SELECT statement against this NEW_Test_TABLE.

```
SELECT * FROM NEW_Test_TABLE
```

Your Query will never finish executing,,, no results will be returned (At this time NEW_Test_TABLE only exists in buffer chache). Unless you go back to your 1st Query Window and commit the transaction, And if you goto query window 1 and `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` NEW_Test_TABLE would have existed once in buffer chache and no longer exist anywhere.

Similarly when your Select into statement in being executed nothing is committed to disk, therefore SSMS cannot see it neither can show you any information about it via Object explorer.

So the answer is while the query is being executed be patient and let SQL Server Commit the `SELECT INTO` transaction to disk and you will be able to access it VIA querying it or via Object explorer.

Comment: In portuguese we have an expression which says: "patience and chicken soup never hurt anyone". I was afraid that was the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As M.Ali explained, SELECT INTO has a table lock on your new table, which is also locking the schema objects that SSMS is trying to query in order to build the tree browser.

I would suggest tuning the query so that the statement can run faster.  Since this is inserting into a Heap with no indexes and has the tablock, it will be minimally logged as you stated.  So it is likely the SELECT part of the statement that is causing things to be slow.  See if that query can be optimized or broken into smaller pieces so that the statement does not run so long.

Alternatively, perform the insert in smaller batches using INSERT INTO (and not specifying the tablock hint)

Comment: Thanks. I think I will convert this `SELECT INTO` in a loop of `INSERT INTO` committing them partially. It will take longer to run, but will not lock the object explorer.