# “SELECT INTO” causes any table locks on the SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * 
into BCK_PH 
from purchase_history
where cast(end_dt as date) <= '2018-06-30';
```

Do we get any table locks and any performance issue, if we run the above query? is there any alternative

Comment: SQL server can escalate locks to table lock, yes - it depends on history length. You can use `nolock`hint, if you are sure that such old data will not updated during execution.

Comment: Try to create index by `end_dt` and then use a condition without `cast` - `where end_dt< '2018-07-01'`.

Comment: [Link](https://dzone.com/articles/when-to-use-the-selectinto-statement) might help.

Comment: Using `NOLOCK` doesn't stop locks, @Arvo .

Comment: @Larnu Well, you are right of course - but lock (using `nolock`hint) is of different kind (schema only) and allows other processes more access.

Comment: @Arvo It can also cause errors and it can have undesirable effects. Quite simply, don't suggest something as a "fix" unless you also mention the problems that go with the "fix".

Comment: @SMor This was not suggested as "fix" (there was no specific problem to fix anyway), but rather as keyword to research. Apparently my wording was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The base table that is "purchase_history" will be accessible during the query execution time. But the new table "BCK_PH" only be available to access just after the query execution finished. [Click for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272245/locking-database-on-select-into).